# Custom highliting of lines in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following pgfplot TeX code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[ 
                xtick={
                    5, 10
                },
                xticklabels={
                    $x$, $2x$
                },
                ytick={
                    -0.60,  0,  0.6
                },
                yticklabels={$-I(x)/2x$ , $0$,  $I(x)/2x$
                },
                axis x line=center,
                axis y line=left,
                ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2,
                xmin=4.5, xmax=10.5,
                xlabel= \footnotesize $y$,  
                ylabel= \footnotesize $g(y)$
                ] 
                %\addplot[domain=5:10,samples = 500] {2*sin(deg(x*cos(deg(x))))/sqrt(x)}; 
                %funcion sin(x*cosx)/sqrt(x)
                \addplot[domain=5:10,samples = 500] {7*sin(deg(2.5*x))*cos(deg(x))/x}; 
                \draw[dashed] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0.6) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0.6);
                \draw[dashed] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},-0.6) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},-0.6);

                \draw[very thick] (axis cs:5.37,0) -- (axis cs:6.05,0);
                \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 5.37,0.6) -- (axis cs: 5.37,0);
                \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 6.05,0.6) -- (axis cs: 6.05,0);

                \draw[ultra thick] (axis cs:6.53,0) -- (axis cs:7.10,0);
                \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 6.53,-0.6) -- (axis cs: 6.53,0);
                \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 7.10,-0.6) -- (axis cs: 7.10,0);

                \draw[very thick] (axis cs:9.18,0) -- (axis cs:9.64,0);
                \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 9.18,0.6) -- (axis cs: 9.18,0);
                \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 9.64,0.6) -- (axis cs: 9.64,0);
                \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
```

This code generates a graphic of a certain function, and it highlights 3 intervals of the x axis, by drawing a thick line on these intervals. I wonder if there is any other type of highlighting such as the one showed in the first interval of this picture (modified with paint):[image]

The reason to do this is that I will highlight other intervals later, and these will overlap with the original ones, so I need both to be easily visible. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of drawing an `ultra thick` line, you could draw a rectangle and fill it with a pattern from `\usetikzlibrary{patterns}`.

Available patterns are: `horizontal lines`, `vertical lines`, `north east lines`, `north west lines`, `grid`, `crosshatch`, `dots`, `crosshatch dots`, `fivepointed stars`, `sixpointed stars`, `bricks`, `checkerboard`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[   xtick       = {5, 10},
                        xticklabels = {$x$, $2x$},
                        ytick       = {-0.60,  0,  0.6},
                        yticklabels = {$-I(x)/2x$ , $0$,  $I(x)/2x$},
                        axis x line = center,
                        axis y line = left,
                        ymin        = -1.2,
                        ymax        = 1.2,
                        xmin        = 4.5,
                        xmax        = 10.5,
                        xlabel      = \footnotesize $y$,
                        ylabel      = \footnotesize $g(y)$
                    ]

            \addplot[domain=5:10,samples = 500] {7*sin(deg(2.5*x))*cos(deg(x))/x};

            \draw[dashed] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0.6) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0.6);
            \draw[dashed] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},-0.6) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},-0.6);

            \fill[pattern=north west lines, pattern color = blue] (axis cs:5.37,-.02) -- (axis cs:5.37,.02) -- (axis cs:6.05,.02) -- (axis cs:6.05,-.02) -- cycle;
            \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 5.37,0.6) -- (axis cs: 5.37,0);
            \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 6.05,0.6) -- (axis cs: 6.05,0);

            \fill[pattern=crosshatch, pattern color = green] (axis cs:6.53,-.02) -- (axis cs:6.53,.02) -- (axis cs:7.10,.02) -- (axis cs:7.10,-.02) -- cycle;
            \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 6.53,-0.6) -- (axis cs: 6.53,0);
            \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 7.10,-0.6) -- (axis cs: 7.10,0);

            \fill[pattern=north east lines, pattern color = red] (axis cs:9.18,-.02) -- (axis cs:9.18,.02) -- (axis cs:9.64,.02) -- (axis cs:9.64,-.02) -- cycle;
            \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 9.18,0.6) -- (axis cs: 9.18,0);
            \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 9.64,0.6) -- (axis cs: 9.64,0);
        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Overlap example:

```
\fill[pattern=north west lines, pattern color = blue] (axis cs:5.37,-.03) -- (axis cs:5.37,.03) -- (axis cs:7.10,.03) -- (axis cs:7.10,-.03) -- cycle;
\draw[dotted] (axis cs: 5.37,0.6) -- (axis cs: 5.37,0);
\draw[dotted] (axis cs: 6.05,0.6) -- (axis cs: 6.05,0);

\fill[pattern=north east lines, pattern color = red] (axis cs:6.05,.03) -- (axis cs:6.05,-.03) -- (axis cs:6.53,-.03) -- (axis cs:6.53,.03) -- cycle;
\draw[dotted] (axis cs: 6.53,-0.6) -- (axis cs: 6.53,0);
\draw[dotted] (axis cs: 7.10,-0.6) -- (axis cs: 7.10,0);
```

[image]

Patterns are not the only solution. If you want to use colour blocks instead, you can play with the `opacity` setting to show a nice overlap:

```
\fill[color=blue, opacity=.5] (axis cs:5.37,-.03) -- (axis cs:5.37,.03) -- (axis cs:6.53,.03) -- (axis cs:6.53,-.03) -- cycle;
\fill[color=red, opacity=.5] (axis cs:6.05,.03) -- (axis cs:6.05,-.03) -- (axis cs:7.10,-.03) -- (axis cs:7.10,.03) -- cycle;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this answer was precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: If you add to preamble `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` or newest pgfplots version (`\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`) than you can omit all `axis cs:` in coordinates in your MWE.